Old horror movie (recoloured?) with gypsy children
I'm trying to identify an old, obscure horror movie.  A rich landholder adopts and then kills gypsy children to give himself immortality.  Two of the children, brother and sister, return to haunt him, ultimately to his death.  In one of the final scenes the two dead (and grossly green) children pursue him, arms outstretched, hideously long curled fingernails reaching for him, while the boy plays an accordion.  They are singing.  Can anyone help please?

Sounds like Lost Hearts, the 1973 BBC adaptation of a 1904 story. From Wiki:

The tale tells the story of Stephen, a young orphan boy, who is sent to stay with his much older cousin at a remote country mansion. His cousin is a reclusive alchemist obsessed with making himself immortal. Stephen is repeatedly troubled by visions of a young gypsy girl and a traveling Italian boy with their hearts missing.

You can see the dead boy and girl in the clip below; they have bluish\green skin and long fingernails, and the boy plays a hurdy-gurdy (I think they also sing around the house):



It turns out the old cousin had burned their hearts and drank the ashes to be immortal, but in the end, the 2 ghost children avenge their deaths by ripping out his heart.

Thank you very much!  That's it.  M.R James :-)  I managed to turn a hurdy gurdy into an accordion. Now I can have a REAL horror movie night again - with nachos! Thanks again, much appreciated!

@Michelle You're quite welcome! Don't forget to click on the V sign to close the question.
